# Create SSL connection using Winsock

Tags: c++, c, ssl

I'm on windows 8 and I need to create `SSL`-connection to the server. We can create plain non-secured connection via built-in `winsock` API. I'm interesed in if there is a built-in extension for creating `SSL` connection in `winsock`? If so, I'd like to look at the code sample.

Comment: Could you give a reason why OpenSSL, GnuTLS and their many friends are not an option for you? Using a widely used library will make your code more portable and (arguably) more stable and secure.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I'm doing that for learning purposes only.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link to Microsoft's Secure Winsock Programming

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740139(v=vs.85).aspx

As it describes you can use Schannel (Secure Channel) Check it out here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123(v=vs.85).aspx